# Youku embed with title of video?

Tags: json, video, embed

I need to fetch the video title as well as the video itself in the iframe/ embed object for Youku. When you embed a youtube video on a page, it has the title of the video within the embed showing, I need the same thing for Youku. I have exhausted my search for the solution online. Any ideas?